# Logic error? Python error catching & variables

Tags: python

I'm writing this piece of code for a Battleships project i'm doing and I believe I've come across a logic error when assigning the pieces to the board in a subroutine.

"and (c == (x+1) or c == (x-1)) and (b == (y+1) or b == (y-1))"

- I believe my error rests in this part of the conditional here, but I cant seem to see where the error is. My error in code likely does not lie anywhere else because when this is replaced with another test conditional, IE the initial conditional looked on at the first part of the subroutine "if c in range(0,3) and b in range(0,3)", It is able to plot down the string "X" as it should

```
#FUNCTION - PLACE TILES
grid = [["  ","  ","  "],["  ","  ","  "],["  ","  ","  "]]
mrk = "X"
cruiser = 2

while True:
    try:
        x,y = input("which tile would you like to place your ship on?").split(",")
        x = int(x)
        y = int(y)
        if x in range(0,3) and y in range(0,3):
            grid[x][y] = mrk
            cruiser -= 1
        else:
            x,y = input("which tile would you like to place your ship on?").split(",")
        break
    except ValueError:
        x,y = input("INVALID CHARACTER\n\nwhich tile would you like to place your ship on?").split(",")

while cruiser < 2 and cruiser > 0:
    while True:
        try:
            c,b = input("which tile would you like to place your ship on?").split(",")
            c = int(c)
            b = int(b)
            print(c,b,x,y)
            if c in range(0,3) and b in range(0,3) and (c == (x+1) or c == (x-1)) and (b == (y+1) or b == (y-1)) :
                grid[c][b] = mrk
                cruiser -= 1

            else:
                c,b = input("INVALID POSITION\n\nwhich tile would you like to place your ship on?").split(",")
            break
        except ValueError:
            c,b = input("INVALID CHARACTER\n\nwhich tile would you like to place your ship on?").split(",")



print (grid[0][0]," | ",grid[0][1]," | ",grid[0][2])
print (grid[1][0]," | ",grid[1][1]," | ",grid[1][2])
print (grid[2][0]," | ",grid[2][1]," | ",grid[2][2])
```

As it uses try and except, no error messages are produced - However, INVALID POSITION as shown in my code, does come up. It should be accepting the value, checking it to see if it lines up ONLY horizontally or vertically with another point, then plotting it.

*Edit : The HTML/CSS snippet gives you a visual of what im trying to do, thanks*

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: auto / auto auto auto;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  background-color: #000000;
  padding: 0px;
}

.grid-container>div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>


  <p1> If the top right X was the first value plotted, valid positions for X would be everything marked X1, and invalid positions would be marked Y </p1>
  <div class="grid-container">
    <div class="item1">X</div>
    <div class="item2">X1</div>
    <div class="item3">X1</div>
    <div class="item4">X1</div>
    <div class="item5">Y</div>
    <div class="item6">Y</div>
    <div class="item7">X1</div>
    <div class="item8">Y</div>
    <div class="item9">Y</div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Sorry for the overkill on the amount of code pasted in - I just see it as relevant to post the entire subroutine in order to help solve this issue. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you have `while cruiser < 2 and cruiser > 0:` and `while True:` inside of it? Doesn't seem to add anything to the code, other than complexity.

Comment: It's important that the second value isn't accessed until the first has been placed. I could remove the "cruiser < 2", although the "cruiser > 0" is key as to stop that part of the code when the pieces have been set down.

Comment: The way I see it, you could remove the `while True:` from inside the other `while` loop without making any different to the code's working.

Comment: What is the input?

Comment: @Goyo You can have an input of 0 , 1 and 2 for each of the inputs (x,y,c,b)

Comment: That is three values for four inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure if I understood what you wanted to do, but I'd replace this

```py
and (c == (x+1) or c == (x-1)) and (b == (y+1) or b == (y-1))
```

by

```py
and c != x and b != y
```

Seems to me that you just want to confirm that `c` and `b` are not in the same positions as `x` and `y`.

**Update:**
Given the new information that you actually want every new marker to be placed at an adjacent position from the previous one, but not in the diagonals, you should indeed store the last marker's position (e.g. `prev_x`, `prev_y`) and update it at each valid input, so you can compare against the new values for the next input and so forth.

Aside from that, to prevent markers from being placed at the diagonals, I don't think there's a magic formula. You need to check whether `c` and `b` are not in the diagonals.

```py
[...]
    # avoid diagonals in relation to the previous marker
    and not (c == prev_x - 1 and b == prev_y - 1)
    and not (c == prev_x - 1 and b == prev_y + 1)
    and not (c == prev_x + 1 and b == prev_y - 1)
    and not (c == prev_x + 1 and b == prev_y + 1)
[...]
```

Comment: I want to make sure that they're not in the same positions as x & y and i want the values (where the string "X" is presented) to align vertically or horizontally but not diagonally with the first value

Comment: @I.Abbas And which values are you inputting for all 4 variables? Are you sure you're typing possible values for `b` and `c`, within the `0, 1, 2` range and considering the values you put for `x` and `y`?

Comment: Yes. I've tried a normal test whereby i feed x and y values of 0 and 1 respectively and I feed c and b values of 0 and 2, I still get an error.

Comment: @I.Abbas On a related note, I see that you just added an HTML explanation of how it should look. From my understanding, if you start with `x, y = 0, 0`, your code will not allow `c, b = 0, 2`, for instance, as you only allow a distance of `1` from the initial marker.

Comment: Exactly, and that's what i was trying to do with the x+1 and x-1 stuff, whereby the code has to check that the position of the marker is a maximum distance of 1 from the origin.

Comment: @I.Abbas Yeah, but in your HTML example, you say that 0,2 and 2,0 are valid positions if the first marker is in 0,0, but your code will not allow that, that's what I mean.

Comment: I'm confounded as to why it won't allow it, could you explain please?

Comment: @I.Abbas If your initial marker is `x, y = 0, 0`, once you input `c, b = 0, 2`, when you do the comparison `and (b == (y+1) or b == (y-1))`, it will fail, as `b == y + 2`. It will also fail as `c == x`, which is another premise you avoid in your condition. Essentially, the only allowed position seems to be the immediate diagonal from the initial marker, exactly what you're trying to avoid.

Comment: Therefore, would it be effective if i had a variable (or two, for x and y), initially assigned a "None" value, which would effectively record the last position for a comparison to see if the value is 1 position away?

Comment: @I.Abbas If your intent is to only allow a new marker to be placed at an adjacent position in relation to the previous one, yes, that could work. The way it is now it can only be placed in an adjacent (diagonal!) position from the initial marker, no matter how many markers you've added already.

Comment: I've done that and now I see that it works, except also in diagonal motion, which brings me back to my initial problem. Is there some sort of (mathematical) formula i can employ to check if the coordinates are adjacent to the marker before?

Comment: @I.Abbas I've edited my answer to provide a new answer to your question, now that it's clearer.

Comment: @I.Abbas Let me know if it worked for you and please don't forget to mark the answer as the correct one if it helped you achieve the solution to your problem, so people can refer to it in the future :)